# Htaccess Blocking Font Awesome Web Fonts?

Tags: css, .htaccess, font-awesome, webfonts

I believe something from within my htaccess file is blocking webfonts from being displayed on my site. I'm not 100% on this, but I've disabled security plugins and everything on my site and it's still happening. Was wondering if someone more experienced could shed some light?

These are the errors I'm getting (*visiting the links pulls a 403 error*):

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147746065
>   source: http://brandonmoner.me/wp-content/plugins/bean-shortcodes/assets/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0 bean-shortcodes.css
>
> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147746065
>   source: http://brandonmoner.me/wp-content/plugins/bean-shortcodes/assets/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0 bean-shortcodes.css

***And here's what's in my htaccess thus far:***

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# TURN OFF YOUR SERVER SIGNATURE
ServerSignature Off

# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP

# BEGIN EXPIRE HEADERS
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END EXPIRE HEADERS

# BEGIN CACHE-CONTROL HEADERS
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END CACHE-CONTROL HEADERS

# DO NOT SHOW DIRECTORY LISTING
# If you are getting 500 Errors then comment out Options -Indexes
# by adding a # sign in front of it. If there is a typo anywhere in this file you will also see 500 errors.
Options -Indexes

# DIRECTORY INDEX FORCE INDEX.PHP
# Use index.php as default directory index file
# index.html will be ignored will not load.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html /index.php

# DENY ACCESS TO PROTECTED SERVER FILES AND FOLDERS
# Files and folders starting with a dot: .htaccess, .htpasswd, .errordocs, .logs
RedirectMatch 403 \.(htaccess|htpasswd|errordocs|logs)$

# WP-ADMIN/INCLUDES
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]

# WP REWRITE LOOP START
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# REQUEST METHODS FILTERED
# This filter is for blocking junk bots and spam bots from making a HEAD request, but may also block some
# HEAD request from bots that you want to allow in certains cases. This is not a security filter and is just
# a nuisance filter. This filter will not block any important bots like the google bot. If you want to allow
# all bots to make a HEAD request then remove HEAD from the Request Method filter.
# The TRACE, DELETE, TRACK and DEBUG request methods should never be allowed against your website.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

# PLUGINS/THEMES AND VARIOUS EXPLOIT FILTER SKIP RULES
# IMPORTANT!!! If you add or remove a skip rule you must change S= to the new skip number
# Example: If RewriteRule S=5 is deleted than change S=6 to S=5, S=7 to S=6, etc.

# Adminer MySQL management tool data populate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/adminer/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=12]
# Comment Spam Pack MU Plugin - CAPTCHA images not displaying
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/mu-plugins/custom-anti-spam/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=11]
# Peters Custom Anti-Spam display CAPTCHA Image
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/peters-custom-anti-spam-image/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=10]
# Status Updater plugin fb connect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/fb-status-updater/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=9]
# Stream Video Player - Adding FLV Videos Blocked
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/stream-video-player/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=8]
# XCloner 404 or 403 error when updating settings
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=7]
# BuddyPress Logout Redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=6]
# redirect_to=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} redirect_to=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=5]
# Login Plugins Password Reset And Redirect 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=resetpass&key=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=4]
# Login Plugins Password Reset And Redirect 2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=rp&key=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=3]

# TIMTHUMB FORBID RFI and MISC FILE SKIP/BYPASS RULE
# Only Allow Internal File Requests From Your Website
# To Allow Additional Websites Access to a File Use [OR] as shown below.
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*YourWebsite.com.* [OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*AnotherWebsite.com.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(http|https|ftp)(%3A|:)(%2F|/)(%2F|/)(w){0,3}.?(blogger|picasa|blogspot|tsunami|petapolitik|photobucket|imgur|imageshack|wordpress\.com|img\.youtube|tinypic\.com|upload\.wikimedia|kkc|start-thegame).*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(http|https|ftp)(%3A|:)(%2F|/)(%2F|/)(w){0,3}.?(blogger|picasa|blogspot|tsunami|petapolitik|photobucket|imgur|imageshack|wordpress\.com|img\.youtube|tinypic\.com|upload\.wikimedia|kkc|start-thegame).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (timthumb\.php|phpthumb\.php|thumb\.php|thumbs\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*brandonmoner.me.*
RewriteRule . - [S=1]

# BEGIN QUERY STRING EXPLOITS
# The libwww-perl User Agent is forbidden - Many bad bots use libwww-perl modules, but some good bots use it too.
# Good sites such as W3C use it for their W3C-LinkChecker.
# Add or remove user agents temporarily or permanently from the first User Agent filter below.
# If you want a list of bad bots / User Agents to block then scroll to the end of this file.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (havij|libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|clshttp|loader) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|\(|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%28|%3C|%3E|%00).*(libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/\*\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} cgi-bin [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (%0A|%0D|\\r|\\n) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} owssvr\.dll [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.opendirviewer\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} users\.skynet\.be.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\./|%2e%2e%2f|%2e%2e/|\.\.%2f|%2e\.%2f|%2e\./|\.%2e%2f|\.%2e/) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=\|w\| [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*embed.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^e]*e)+mbed.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*object.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^o]*o)+bject.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\(|\)|<|>|%3c|%3e).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\x00|\x04|\x08|\x0d|\x1b|\x20|\x3c|\x3e|\x7f).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (NULL|OUTFILE|LOAD_FILE) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.{1,}/)+(motd|etc|bin) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \-[sdcr].*(allow_url_include|allow_url_fopen|safe_mode|disable_functions|auto_prepend_file) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|drop|delete|update|cast|create|char|convert|alter|declare|order|script|set|md5|benchmark|encode) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
# END QUERY STRING EXPLOITS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# WP REWRITE LOOP END

# DENY BROWSER ACCESS TO THESE FILES
# wp-config.php, bb-config.php, php.ini, php5.ini, readme.html
# Replace Allow from 88.77.66.55 with your current IP address and remove the
# pound sign # from in front of the Allow from line of code below to access these
# files directly from your browser.

<FilesMatch "^(wp-config\.php|php\.ini|php5\.ini|readme\.html|bb-config\.php)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
#Allow from 88.77.66.55
</FilesMatch>

# BLOCK HOTLINKING TO IMAGES
# To Test that your Hotlinking protection is working visit http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?brandonmoner\.me [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
#RewriteRule .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: That’s a lot of rewriting (and other stuff) going on there (and it looks quite chaotic too) – so I suggest you disable parts of this to try and find out what’s blocking access to the fonts. And a look into the server’s error log might also provide useful information.

Comment: [.htaccess example](http://support.maxcdn.com/tutorials/htaccess-examples/) may help you find out the error.

Comment: @Gunaseelan Thanks for that. Definitely going to make use of that.

Comment: Ok so currently I've gotten rid of all but the most basic rules required by WordPress in the HTACCESS file. I've also completely deleted one of the security plug-ins. And the one that's left, I thoroughly checked and there's not an option in that that would be disrupting the flow of information on my site.

I also switched from the local install, back to the hosted CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file should only control accesses to *your* site. If you're getting a 403 error going to an external site, it's likely that *they* are blocking you for some reason. Maybe they think you're trying to scrape/bulk load their site, or you come from a disallowed IP address, or your User Agent is on a prohibited list or something. You'll probably have to ask the other site about what restrictions they place. It wouldn't be surprising if they're trying to prevent "hot linking" of their resources.

Comment: I think the font files _are_ under his domain – within his very own `wp-content` folder …

Comment: @bmoneruxui, could you clarify whether you're being blocked from accessing your _own_ site's resources, or if they're on some other site?

Comment: Well when I use their hosted CDN method, it says that it failed to download the font from the CDN path. And then when I do a local installation, it says it's failed with the message listed above. And I don't think they are blocking me for scraping as that's a heavily used resource by a lot of people. And upon first implementation it's not working either way.

Comment: If you're getting a 403 on a _local_ access, the most likely cause is something in your .htaccess for "hot link" protection (that perhaps fails to whitelist your [sub]domain), or some hack protection (UQS content) that happens to be triggering on your URL. You've already checked for adequate directory and file permissions? I'm afraid it's time for trial-and-error searching through your .htaccess file(s)!

Comment: Thanks for you guys help. I'll get to the grit and see what I can find out.